# How does udev create /dev/sr*? (Or: Which rule does create /dev/sr*?)

Tags: linux, kernel, udev

udev is responsible for populating /dev. It adds and removes device nodes to /dev dynamically based on rules/configs/scripts under /lib/udev and /etc/udev/.

If I have a CDROM device node /dev/sr0 I can add a symlink /dev/cdrom by adding a [rule like](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-cdrom):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", SYMLINK+="cdrom", GROUP="cdrom"
```

I understand how symlinks are created in udev. But who (or "which rule") created /dev/sr0 (or another non symlink device node) in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default device, based on the kernel name (`sr0` in this case) is always created automatically as a real device file, so no rule is needed for that.

Additional synonyms are then created by writing rules which specify symlinks to be added which point at the real file.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Googling for "default device node"  brought up this link: [Dynamic Kernel Device Management with udev](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.udev.html).
In 12.6 it says "If no matching rule is found, the default device node name is used to create the device node." 
(Unfortunately I cant vote up since I dont have 15 reputation.)

Comment: You realize that you can add symlinks at any time, not just in udev configuration file.

Comment: Well of course - the point of doing it as a udev rule is that it will persist when you reboot, or when you unplug the device and then plug it back in again.

Comment: Adding any symbolic links via `ln -s` will be removed after reboot. But you can add static devices by adding them to /lib/udev/devices without creating a rule.